# Splitting datatframe into test data and train data based on date-range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to split a dataframe into a traindata of the date range 3/1/2016 to 2/31/2018 and test data of the range  3/1/2018 to 3/31/2018 using python?Here date is of the type date object

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried yourself? Now it just looks like you want us to do your work :)

Comment: you can use the date_range function, make those dates your index, and then create a seprate DataFrame strictly with that data. Or you can use the [:] slice operate to make a copy of that data for those dates, store it in a variable and work with that data. Or you can use the .head()/.tail() methods and as the arg enter the number of rows of data that you want to work with. Many ways to go about this.